# Can't connect to a specific website from my network only (all other networks connect)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet-connection, ping

**Problem summary:**

A few days ago, I stopped being able to connect to my uni's network ([iastate.edu](http://www.iastate.edu/)), and all other services existing on my uni's network (grade tracking app, vpn, registration, course pages, etc.).

No devices on my home network can connect to iastate.edu, but all of my devices can connect from any other network. **I can reach any other website from my network just fine.**

**Here's what I've Tried:**

- Pinging iastate.edu from my terminal on my home network

  - Failed (of course).  `Request timeout for icmp_seq N`
- Pinging iastate.edu from [an online ping service](http://ping.eu/)

  - This worked.  Ping.eu was successfully able to ping iastate.edu (129.186.1.99) 100% of the time.
- Manually entering '129.186.1.99' in my browser (chrome/firefox)

  - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
- Connecting my laptop to my modem directly (bypassing my wireless router) and attempting to load iastate.edu via chrome

  - This worked.  Indicates to me that the issue lies somewhere in my wireless router....
- Factory resetting/reconfiguring my wireless router

  - Still no dice
- Signed up for OpenDNS and configured my router to use that for its DNS

  - Still can't load iastate.edu
- Calling my university to make sure I haven't been blacklisted for some reason

  - I haven't been blacklisted
- Calling my ISP's tech support.

  - Nothing useful from them...

**My hardware and ISP**

- Wireless router:  Netgear WNDR4500v2
- ISP: Mediacom Communications Corporation

I'm at a loss now.  I don't know what to try next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For what it's worth, here's output from a traceroute I tried:

```
$ traceroute 129.186.1.99
traceroute to 129.186.1.99 (129.186.1.99), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  6.762 ms  8.990 ms  4.547 ms
 2  * * *
 3  172.30.1.157 (172.30.1.157)  22.722 ms  28.007 ms  28.574 ms
 4  97-64-179-218.client.mchsi.com (97.64.179.218)  31.360 ms  22.669 ms  31.374 ms
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
```

Comment: Sounds like it's time to try a new/different router.

Comment: Instead of open DNS as the default dns provider on the router, just try google's dns servers. `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Your ISP is mchsi.com. It is their network that seems to be broken. Send a copy of the tracert to their tech support and ask to speak to 2nd level support.