# Example.com "Unable to Connect" from home network

Tags: router, browser, url, isp

I cannot connect to www.example.com through my home network, and I don't know why.

Details of the home network:

- On the outside, I have a DSL connection to a Zyxel C3000Z router.
- On the inside, I have multiple devices and multiple OSes connected to the router via both cable and Wifi.

Symptoms of the problem: what it is, what it isn't

- When I try to connect to https://wwww.example.com, Firefox gives me the "Unable to Connect" page. Other browsers give similar pages.
- When I try to connect to http://www.example.com, I get redirected to webhelper.centurylink.com. (NOTE: This is new behavior, the result of a service call to CenturyLink today. Before today, this URL also resulted in the "Unable to Connect" page.)
- The failure does not occur with www.example.org. The failure only occurs with www.example.com.
- The failure occurs with all devices and all OSes.

I found a related issue, [Can't connect to a specific website from my network only (other networks connect)](https://superuser.com/questions/1142052/cant-connect-to-a-specific-website-from-my-network-only-all-other-networks-con). Starting from there:

- ping example.com works, but ping www.example.com doesn't work.
- Manually entering the www.example.com IP address (198.105.244.23) prefixed with http or https doesn't help.
- Rebooting the C3000Z doesn't help. I didn't reset it to factory settings, though.
- Working on the problem with my ISP's tech support doesn't help.

Here's output from traceroute:

```
$ traceroute 209.67.208.202
traceroute to 209.67.208.202 (209.67.208.202), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  modem.Home (192.168.0.1)  0.644 ms  0.865 ms  1.141 ms
2  hlrn-dsl-gw10.hlrn.qwest.net (207.225.112.10)  21.363 ms  22.398 ms  22.698 ms
3  63-225-124-73.hlrn.qwest.net (63.225.124.73)  23.201 ms  23.601 ms  23.571 ms
4  dal-edge-19.inet.qwest.net (205.171.25.90)  40.399 ms  41.317 ms  41.266 ms
5  204.98.170.222 (204.98.170.222)  43.179 ms  43.550 ms  43.669 ms
6  216.39.83.182 (216.39.83.182)  43.119 ms  37.803 ms  38.653 ms
7  * * *
8  * * *
9  * * *
...
```

Comment: Hmm. www.example.com is 93.184.216.34 for me. And 209.67.208.202 is dclinkhdmwii.clink.motive.com. 198.105.244.23 doesn't resolve but it's got nothing to do with www.example.com.

Comment: 93... it is, then. traceroute 93... resolves successfully. Ping 93... works. Manually entering http://93.... and https://93... both result in 404 Not Found errors.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem by setting DNS server IP addresses manually in the OSes where it was relevant. Details on how to set DNS servers are readily available, and are therefore omitted here.

I still don't know why my ISP doesn't recognize www.example.com, but with the workaround in place, that question is no longer urgent.